Docker Engine won't start after adding "hosts" in daemon.json
I want to enable Docker Api and one of steps is to add
  "hosts": [
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
    "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"
  ]

to ~/.docker/daemon.json file, but after that, Docker engine won't start.
If I remove those lines from daemon.json, engine works.
What is the solution for this in case of macOs ? I found some solutions for Linux systems, but those don't really apply for my situation.

Why do you think you want to enable that option?  Almost all software I know of that can use the Docker API directly knows how to use the standard Unix-socket interface.  Remember that there are significant security risks from allowing programs to access the socket, and opening a network-accessible socket (even only on the local system) can allow bypassing key security controls.
